# Codeigniter storing session in database

Tags: php, facebook, codeigniter, session, facebook-iframe

I am having a problem in storing session in database. My project has two parts one is a complete website where user comes and schedule their video broadcasting and the second part is facebook application where viewer comes and watch the broadcast. The problem is that when i store session in database by setting sess_use_database to true my website part runs fine and no problem occurs but in the facebook part session does not store the manual values except the codeigniters default values but when i use cookies for session both parts runs well. Is there any problem with codeigniter sessions in iframe?

Comment: Not that I know of - I was just working on a CI-driven FB app using sessions and had no problems.

Comment: did you use the session with database???

Answer (score 0):

I guess your problem is that Web servers create unique id sessions for domain names, so if I access your site through facebook my session id will be different than accessing your site through its domain, cookies should be used in this case to store the session id only, but all session data should be stored in the database.

Comment: using cookies have a different problem.... safari does not allow iframe cookies. There is also a third part of my website where users get embed code of their broadcast and paste it to different website the embed code creates the iframe on websites on show their broadcast in this case my session would not be maintained in safari browser thats why i go for the database sessions.

Answer (score 0):

I have been having problems on my project for more than two days trying to debug my problem with sessions UNTILL i found the problem which lies on the ci_session table structure

if you are having problems, your table should be like this:

```
--
-- Table structure for table `ci_sessions`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ci_sessions` (
  `session_id` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `ip_address` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `user_agent` varchar(120) NOT NULL,
  `last_activity` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `user_data` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`session_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```